# Recursively move files in sub-dirs to new sub-dirs of same name

Tags: linux, command-line, bash

I have a batch of files all ending with the same string, ie: `*_ext.dat` located in several sub-dirs along with several other files, in a given main dir. This is the structure:

```
/main_dir/subdir1/file11_ext.dat
/main_dir/subdir1/file12_ext.dat
/main_dir/subdir1/file13_ext.dat
/main_dir/subdir1/file14_other.dat
/main_dir/subdir1/file15_other.dat

/main_dir/subdir2/file21_ext.dat
/main_dir/subdir2/file22_ext.dat
/main_dir/subdir2/file23_ext.dat
/main_dir/subdir2/file24_other.dat
/main_dir/subdir2/file25_other.dat

/main_dir/subdir3/file31_ext.dat
/main_dir/subdir3/file32_ext.dat
/main_dir/subdir3/file33_ext.dat
/main_dir/subdir3/file34_other.dat
/main_dir/subdir3/file35_other.dat
```

I need to recursively move *only* the files ending in `*_ext.dat` into a new main dir, `new_dir`, respecting the sub-dir structure so the files will end up in an equivalent dir structure like this:

```
/new_dir/subdir1/file11_ext.dat
/new_dir/subdir1/file12_ext.dat
/new_dir/subdir1/file13_ext.dat

/new_dir/subdir2/file21_ext.dat
/new_dir/subdir2/file22_ext.dat
/new_dir/subdir2/file23_ext.dat

/new_dir/subdir3/file31_ext.dat
/new_dir/subdir3/file32_ext.dat
/new_dir/subdir3/file33_ext.dat
```

Because of this the command should also *create* those sub-dirs with their corresponding names.
I know that with a line like this one:

```
find . -name "*_ext.dat" -print0 | xargs -0 rm -rf
```

I can *delete* all those files, but I don't know how to modify it to do what I need (or if it is even possible).

Comment: Probably somthing like `rsync --include=*_ext.dat /main_dir/ /new_dir/` will do the trick. Haven't tested it though.

Answer (score 1):

I would first create the subdirectories in `new_dir` by

```
cd main_dir
for i in *; do mkdir "../new_dir/$i"; done
cd ..
```

Then you can use `bash`'s `for` command again along with pattern expansion to do exactly what you need quickly:

```
for i in main_dir/*/*_ext.dat; do cp "$i" "new_dir${i##main_dir}"; done
```

using the fact that the destination directories exist. Finally, if were not guaranteed that *each* of them would actually be used, you can purge the empty ones afterwards:

```
cd new_dir
rmdir --ignore-fail-on-non-empty *
```

Comment: **In the first loop** you are expecting that in the `main_dir` there are only directories. Also you are not double-quoting the paths in all your code so it will not work with file names containing spaces. This code will be much more robust: `for i in */; do mkdir "../new_dir/$i"; done`. --- **The last piece of code** will not remove directories containing empty directories. For that you can use `find`: [How do you remove nested empty directories using a Bash script on Linux?](http://superuser.com/a/597309/61370)

Comment: @pabouk Of course it will. (Perhaps you didn't notice the `cd` preceding it?) Man page of `rmdir` says: "DESCRIPTION ... Remove the DIRECTORY(ies), if they are empty." The option `--ignore-fail-on-non-empty` opts out from the warnings that non-empty directories were left out. Moreover, I tried it on my system before posting.

Comment: Also, the directory structure my commands expect agrees perfectly with the way the OP introduced it including his explicit examples. Of course the commands would be different if the structure was.

Comment: Thanks, though, for the comment on spaces. Fixed.

Comment: You are welcome. You exaggerated with the double quotes. The last command will not do what you want. --- **First loop:** Is not it better to add single `/` so that the code is more universal and works in more use-cases? --- **Last command** does not work: `mkdir a ; cd a ; mkdir -p a/b/c d/e/f g/h/i ; ls ; rmdir --ignore-fail-on-non-empty * ; ls` --- output: `a  d  g` `a  d  g`

Comment: Oh my, of course, I was being stupid with putting "" around a `*`. Thanks a lot!

Comment: In your example, `a d g` are not empty, they contain something (even if that something is an empty directory). In the original question, the subdirs of `new_dir` don't have any further subdirectories, just the copied files—or no files at all in which case I delete them. The intended use case: `mkdir a; cd a; mkdir b c d e; touch b/file1 b/file2 d/file3; ls; rmdir --ignore-fail-on-non-empty *; ls` — output: `b c d e` `b d`

Comment: Excuse me. Now I see that the example in the question has only a single level of directories. Of course your command will work in this case. **Edit:** I noticed that you have `cp` instead of `mv` in your code.